# How too add an argument if my current folder exist in the directory

Tags: r, directory

I have the R code that will create a new folder then will set the directory to the new folder. But I want to add an argument that will check whether the new folder exists in the directory if it does then it wont create the new folder.

Here is my R code

```
path <- getwd()

newfolder <- "New Folder"

dir.create(file.path(path, newfolder))

new_path <- file.path(path, newfolder)

setwd(new_path)
```

I am struggling to add the argument to achieve my goal. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dir.exists()`:

```
fp <- file.path(path, newfolder)

if (!dir.exists(fp)) dir.create(fp)
```